# python operator 'in' versus regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm working on a database of medical terms (mesh and uniprot) and I'm parsing a lot of medical papers (pubmed) searching for matches of terms in the papers. Both numbers are staggering (~300k terms and ~6.5M papers) so the matching algorithm must be as efficient as possible.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
foo = "some long and boring medical paper [...] that I'm searching"
bar = [["array of medical terms matched with an unique code",1],
       ["also they are sorted by length",2]]
for term in bar:
    if term[0] in foo:
        repetitions = foo.count(term[0])
        array_to_be_inserted_in_database.append(term[1],repetitions)
```

Note: `foo` comes from a NLTK corpus generator (omitted to keep example simple) and `array_to_be_inserted_in_database` is as its name says; when I finish a `bar` check I save everything in a MongoDB and go for the next paper.

The question:

I'm not very used to regular expressions, would they be worth it in terms of speed? Also chemical compounds and medical terms are full of escape characters (ex: `(1-5)-methylbuthyl*-ethyl-something`), how do you "neutralize" them so they don't interfere with the RE?

EDIT: self-answer
After some study and testing `in` is faster than REs

```
t= timeit.Timer(
    're.subn(regex,"",frase)',
    setup = 'import re; frase = "el gato gordo de la abuela"; palabra = "gordo"; regex = re.compile(palabra)'


    )
ordenes = """\
if palabra in frase:
    numero = frase.count(palabra)
    frase.replace(palabra,"")
"""
y= timeit.Timer(stmt= ordenes,setup = 'frase = "el gato gordo de la abuela"; palabra = "gordo"'
    )

print t.timeit(number = 1000)
print y.timeit(number = 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only dealing with verbatim strings (instead of patterns), and if you don't mind if a term like `gut` will also match a longer word like `gutter`, then `in` may be faster.

On the other hand, you can use `re.findall()` to do all the matching at once and get the length of the resulting list, so you don't have to go through the string twice (once for finding, once for counting). Neutralising special characters is easy - just call `re.escape()` on the string, and it will make sure that the text is matched as is.

In the end, the only way to say for sure is to test both solutions against real-world data.

Comment: I made some testing with real world data, REs are slower that going through the strings several times

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching all the terms individually, you could create an index on all the papers, listing which words appear in which papers, and then just search the papers that have all the relevant words. This way, you will have to scan each paper once to build the index, and then you just have to do a full text search for those papers of which you know that they contain all the relevant terms.

Very simple pseudocode:

```
# get interesting words
interesting_words = set(word for term in terms for word in term.split())

# build index, mapping interesting words to papers they appear in
index = defaultdict(set)
for paper in papers:
    for word in paper.text:
        if word in interesting_words:
            index[word].add(paper)

# find full terms in papers that have all the words, according to the index
for term in terms:
    interesting = reduce(set.intersection, (index[word] for word in term.split()))
    for paper in interesting:
        if term in interesting.text:
            full term found
```

(Note: I am not an expert in indexing/data retrieval and there are probably much better ways to create such an index, and probably also a few libraries that already do that.)

Comment: More or less that is what I'm doing actually, I'm doing that first scan